How to execute script when files change when serving Angular app
I have a node script that transforms a markdown file (.md) into HTML and places it in a folder in an Angular app. I have a prebuild step in the package.json file that executes this script.
Then... I make edits to the .md file, run npm start and my app magically displays the new HTML... Groovy.
Once the app is served, changes to any file will trigger a rebuild. I'd like to hook into this lifecycle to run my script automatically so I don't have to stop the app and run npm start every time. Is this possible?

have you looked into Nodemon?

Use fs.watch or probably better a wrapper like chokidar. This is what build tools use for this purpose

I guess you can experiment with tsconfig include make sure you have allowjs set to true. This is suggested hoping that the script is a node.js script.
